# Call the content help

Tags: the-content

I bought a template and uploaded it to my wordpress site. I can't seem to edit this page because of a 'call the content'. I have no experience of coding so is there something i can do?

thank you - any help is gratefully appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you added the template of html or full wordpress theme?

Answer (score 0):

According to their site:

> This is not an error. in our template we have coded if content exist
>   then the_content function call otherwise skip the_content function.

So it's necessary to add some text in the page content area then you can use your page builder plugin and the error should be gone.

Not the best way to go about it for a plugin, but that's what they say...